# Azure Data Factory Array of Strings mapped in Copy Activity, Cosmos SQL sink only accepts string and not array of strings?

Tags: arrays, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory Pipeline with a Copy Activity. Source is a JSON file (some generated pipeline variables too) and Sink is a Cosmos SQL Collection. Before Mapping I imported the schema and a particular field from the sink collection has been identified to be of type array [] with string elements.

The problem however is that this field mapping now only accepts a STRING and not an Array of strings. I am not sure if this a bug with ADF or something to do with how I genrated the source variable for this mapping.

[image]

If the source variable accessGroups is of string the copy works fine(it shouldn't though right???). However if I substitute this with a variable containing an array of strings I get the following error:

**Failed to convert the value in 'value' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct. Object must implement IConvertible.**

Just to be clear, I am mapping the source variable accessGroups to ['accessGroups'] and not ['accessGroups'][0]. Besides ADF does not allow mapping source variables to individual array elements anyway.

Any one faced this issue before or aware of any workaround?

Comment: Can you please share your sample input and expected output?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT, My input includes an array of strings Variable. The expected output is that this array of strings input variable is sinked into cosmos 'accessGroups' field illustrated (right hand side red square) in my question. Do you need further clarifications?

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT The input includes a JSON file too. The fields in the JSON I/P include array of objects and strings alike. These are being mapped into Cosmos fields all having array [] any type with out any issues. However the Source has an additional internal variable of type array [] containing string elements. This variable is not being accepted by the cosmosDB mapped field 'accessGroups'. It is expecting a string and not array [] despite the mapped field displaying its type to be of type array[] with string elements (refer screenshot in question)